# Schema for User Ratings - Key/Value DB

Tags: mongodb, database-schema

We're using MongoDB and I'm figuring out a schema for storing Ratings.

- Ratings will have values of 1-5.
- I want to store other values such as `fromUser`

This is fine but the main question I have is setting it up so that recalculating the average is as efficient as possible.

---

SOLUTION 1 - Separate Ratings Class

The first thought was to create a separate `Ratings` class and store an array of pointers to `Ratings` in the `User` class. The reason I second guessed this is that we will have to query for all of the `Ratings` objects every time a new `Rating` comes in so that we can recalculate an average

...

SOLUTION 2 - Dictionary in User Class

The second thought was to store a dictionary in the `User` class directly that would store these `Ratings` objects. This would be slightly more lightweight than Solution 1, but we'd be re-writing the entire `Ratings` history of each user every time we update. This seems dangerous.

...

SOLUTION 3 - Separate Ratings Class with Separate Averages in User Class

Hybrid option where we have `Ratings` in their own class, and a pointer array to them, however, we keep two values in the User Class - `ratingsAve` and `ratingsCount`. This way when a new Rating is set we save that object but we can recalculate the `ratingsAve` easily.

---

SOLUTION 3 sounds best to me but I'm just wondering if we'd need to include periodic calibrations by requerying the Ratings history to reset the `ratingsAve` just to make sure everything checks out.

I might be overthinking this but I'm not that great at DB schema creation, and this seems like a standard schema issue that I should know how to implement.

Which is the best option to ensure consistency but also efficiency of recalculation?

Comment: If there is any misunderstanding for us about your question, let us know to updating our solutions (I don't care about rep but I tested my solution about performance and ..., and I think its good, I just want to know which part I didn't understand about your problem)

Answer (score 36):

First of all 'Dictionary in User Class' is not a good idea. why? Adding extra rate object requires pushing a new item to the array, which implies the old item will be removed, and this insertion is so called "**moving a document**". Moving documents is slow and MongoDB is not so great at reusing empty space, so moving documents around a lot can result in large swaths of empty data file (some text in 'MongoDB The Definitive Guide' book).

Then what is the correct solution: assume you have a collection named Blogs, and want to implement a rating solution for your blog posts, and additionally keep track of every user-based rate operation.

The schema for a blog document would be like:

```
{
   _id : ....,
   title: ....,
   ....
   rateCount : 0,
   rateValue : 0,
   rateAverage: 0
}
```

You need another collection (Rates) with this document schema:

```
{
    _id: ....,
    userId: ....,
    postId:....,
    value: ..., //1 to 5
    date:....   
}
```

And you need to define a proper index for it:

`db.Rates.ensureIndex({userId : 1, postId : 1})// very useful. it will result in a much faster search operation in case you want to check if a user has rated the post previously`

When a user wants to rate, firstly you need to check whether the user has rated the post or not. assume the user is `'user1'`, the query then would be

```
var ratedBefore = db.Rates.find({userId : 'user1', postId : 'post1'}).count()
```

And based on `ratedBefore`, if **`!ratedBefore`** then insert new rate-document to Rates collection and update blog status, otherwise, user is not allowed to rate

```
if(!ratedBefore)
{
    var postId = 'post1'; // this id sould be passed before by client driver
    var userId = 'user1'; // this id sould be passed before by client driver
    var rateValue = 1; // to 5
    var rate = 
    {       
       userId: userId,
       postId: postId,
       value: rateValue,
       date:new Date()  
    };

    db.Rates.insert(rate);
    db.Blog.update({"_id" : postId}, {$inc : {'rateCount' : 1, 'rateValue' : rateValue}});
}
```

Then what is gonna happen to `rateAverage`?
I strongly recommend to calculate it based on `rateCount` and `rateValue` on client side, it is easy to update `rateAverage` with `mongoquery`, but you shouldn't do it. why? The simple answer is: this is a very easy job for client to handle these kind of works and putting average on every blog document needs an unnecessary update operation.

the average query would be calculated as:

```
var blog = db.Blog.findOne({"_id" : "post1"});
var avg = blog.rateValue / blog.rateCount;
print(avg);
```

With this approach you will get maximum performance with mongodb an you have track of every rate based by user, post and date.

Comment: On note: Adding an item to an array does not necessarily force MongoDB to move the document. Only if the [padding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-padding) is exceeded, the document will be moved to prevent document level fragmentation.

Comment: @Markus W Mahlberg is totally right, but pushing lots of items to an array is not a good idea http://askasya.com/post/largeembeddedarrays

Comment: I am aware of that ;) I just wanted to point out that adding an item to an array does not automatically force a document move.

Comment: Could you explain how to query in a performant way if a batch of posts was rated by a user? I've found the $in operator like this: db.Rates.find({ postId: { $in: postIds }, userId: user }) but the order gets not kept. Thanks

Comment: I think that keeping in the database the average make sense if you want, at some point, sort the collection by popularity or rate_average. Otherwise this sort criteria can not be provided by the API... isn't?

Comment: Probably adding unique constraint on the combined index will even ensure that only one unique rating is given per user. 

db.Rates.ensureIndex({userId : 1, postId : 1}, {unique: true})

Answer (score 4):

My solution is quite simple, similar to your 3rd option but more simpler. Let's said we have 3 models: `Book`, `User` and `Rating`. I added new field call `totalRated` - array of int to `Book` model to store total Rated counting, the value is mapping `index + 1`.

Your rating system from 1-5, so, `totalRated` means:

- `[total1star, total2star, total3star, total4star, total5star]`

Every time user rate this Book, I will create a Document on `Rating` collection, and increase the counting by 1 (mapping with the `index+1` of `totalRated` array).

#### The Results is:

- `rateCount` now is sum of each item in array.
- `rateAverage` should be `(index+1 * value) / rateCount`.
- We can get total number rate by value mapping with `index + 1` too.

#### Step by step

For default, this should be:

```
// Book Document
{
 _id,
 totalRated: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 ...otherFields
}
```

- If user1 rate 5 star for this book, the document now should be:

```
{
 _id,
 totalRated: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 ...otherFields
}
```

- If user2 rate 4 star for this book, the document now should be:

```
{
 _id,
 totalRated: [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
 ...otherFields
}
```

- If user3 rate 4 star for this book, the document now should be:

```
{
 _id,
 totalRated: [0, 0, 0, 2, 1],
 ...otherFields
}
```

- rateCount = `0 + 0 + 0 + 2 + 1` = 3
- rateAverage = `(0*1 + 0*2 + 0*3 + 2*4 + 1*5)/3` = 4.33...

Note: You can change array int to array object, the key should be rating value, and value should be totalRating, but array int is enough for me.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it a bit different: Have a User class and a Rating class and aggregate the number of ratings and rating average.

#### The Rating class

This is a bit of pseudo code, but the meaning should be obvious.

```
{
  _id:ObjectId(…),
  rating: Integer,
  rater: User._id
  rated: User._id
  date: ISODate()
}
```

In order to do the aggregation efficiently, you should *at least* create an index over `rated`:

```
db.ratings.ensureIndex({rated:1})
```

Now, you can decide between to approaches: either, you calculate the number of ratings and the average let's say once an hour and store it in an collection, let's say `rate_averages`, or you calculate those values on demand.

#### Precalculated

```
db.ratings.aggregate(
  // Aggregation
  [{
     $order: {
      _id: "$rated",
      ratings: { $sum:1 },
      average: { $avg: "$rating" }
    },
    {$out:'rate_averages'}
  ]
)
```

A document in the `rate_averages` collection will then look like this:

```
{
  _id:User._id,
  ratings: Integer,
  average: Float
}
```

and is easily queryable for the individual user's values, as `_id` is indexed automatically.

#### On demand

You'd use the same rating and almost the same aggregation query, except that we add a `$match` stage so we only work with the values for the user we want to know the stats for and leave out the `$out` stage and have the document to be returned directly:

```
db.ratings.aggregate([
  {
    $match:{ rated: <_id of the user we want the values for> },
  },
  {
    $order: {
      _id: "$rated",
      ratings: { $sum:1 },
      average: { $avg: "$rating" }
  }
])
```

which would return a single document as shown for the user in question.

With this approach and a proper data model, you can even do such things as "How many ratings were given by a specific user on a given date?" or "What are the most active raters/the most rated?" quite easily.

Please read the [aggregation framework docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) for further details. You might find the [data modeling docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/) useful, too.

Answer (score 1):

The Below code can be used to get the average rating for each users.

```
db.ratings.aggregate([
 {
 $match:{ rated: '$user' },
 },
 {
 $order: {
  _id: "$rated",
  average: { $avg: "$rating" }
 }
 ])
```

Comment: this is referring to which solution?